# Angular view not rendered but route URL changing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my Angular 9 app the blog-detail view is not changing on clicking the recent-blog component but the router URL is changing on the browser. But when I'm manually refreshing the page with the newly acquired URL, the view now changes successfully. You can check my repository [here](https://github.com/tridibc2/sample-angular/). Below is my code that I did for the routing and rendering of the components

routing-module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'blog/:id', component: BlogDetailComponent}];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RecentBlogComponent,BlogCategoryComponent,BlogDetailComponent ],
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),CommonModule,ClientRoutingModule, FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,RecentBlogComponent,BlogCategoryComponent,BlogDetailComponent]})
export class ClientModule { }
```

blog-detail.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col bottom">
      <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="currentBlog">
        <h1>{{currentBlog.title}}</h1><hr>
         <div class="img-responsive"><img src="http://localhost/Angular7Blog/api/uploads/{{currentBlog.image}}" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <hr><br>
         <div [innerHtml]="currentBlog.description"></div>
      </div></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 order-2 order-md-2" style="margin-top: 1.1%;">
      <app-recent-blog></app-recent-blog>
      <app-blog-category></app-blog-category>
  </div></div></div>
```

blog-detail.component.ts:

```
export class BlogDetailComponent implements OnInit {
   public currentBlog: Blogpost;
     constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private blogpostService: BlogpostService, private titleService: Title) { }
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('blog-detail ngOnInit called')
    let myBlogId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(myBlogId);
    this.blogpostService.getSingleBlogInformation(myBlogId).subscribe(
                (data: Blogpost) =>{ console.log(data); this.currentBlog = data; }
                error =>{ console.log("some error occured");}
```

recent-blog.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h6 class="text-muted">Recent Blogs</h6> 
      <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let blog of blogs">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div class="image-parent">
            <a [routerLink]="['/blog', blog.id]">
              <img src="http://localhost/Angular7Blog/api/uploads/{{blog.image}}" class="img-fluid" alt="image">
            </a>
            </div>
              <a [routerLink]="['/blog', blog.id]">
                {{blog.title}}
              </a></li></ul></div></div></div>
```

Comment: I tried running your code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/tridibc2/sample-angular), but the routing works as expected. Have you found the solution?